# Strings not joining in Python

Tags: python, random, terminal, passwords, generator

I am trying to create a simple password generator using python, it reads a pattern you feed in the following format, `A` for uppercase character, `a` for lower case ones, `$` for a number and `#` for a symbol. The pattern is to be given via a command line argument and output given back by the `sys.exit()` method.

For some reason my script isn't working, it looks fine to me & I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with it. It is outputting a blank line on my terminal window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# IMPORTS
import os
import sys
import random

alc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
auc = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
num = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
sym = ["!", "#", "%", "&", "?", "@", "(", ")", "[", "]", "<", ">", "*", "+", ",", ".", "~", ":", ";", "=", "-", "_", "\\", "/"]

pattern = list(sys.argv[1])
password = ""

# PROCESSING

for x in pattern:
    if x == "A":
        random.shuffle(auc)
        password.join(auc[0])
    elif x == "a":
        random.shuffle(alc)
        password.join(alc[0])
    elif x == "$":
        random.shuffle(num)
        password.join(num[0])
    elif x == "#":
        random.shuffle(sym)
        password.join(sym[0])
    else:
        password = "ERROR: Invalid Syntax."
        break

# END PROCESSING

sys.exit(password)
```

Comment: When you run the script, what do you input as an argument?

Comment: Why password.join ? It should be password+=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, thus when you call `join()`, it doesn't change `password`. It returns the output.

```
password.join(thelist[0])
```

Should be:

```
password = password.join(thelist[0])
```

So when you go to print `password`, only `''` will appear because you never changed it.

`join` isn't even needed here. You can do `password += auc[0]`. I have shown this below.

You can also clean up some stuff in your code too. The [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module will help you:

```
>>> import string
>>> print list(string.lowercase)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> print list(string.uppercase)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> print list(string.punctuation)
['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
>>> print list(string.digits)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

And instead of shuffling the list, you can use `random.choice()`:

```
for x in pattern:
    if x == "A":
        password += random.choice(auc)
    elif ...
```

---

Comment: That made it work better but now it is outputting only the last item in the pattern, when I feed it `AA##$$aa` it just gives me back the last one, a lowercase character. Seems that every pass is overwriting the whole string.

Thanks for the optimisation tip by the way, do you know of anything similar I can do for the `sym` or `num` lists?

Comment: @LuizBerti Hmm, it shouldn't be doing that. Also, I added in solutions for sym and num

Comment: @LuizBerti This is very interesting. It seems that `$` is replaced by some number, before we even do any conversion

Comment: Your response is absolutely brilliant. You not only fixed my code but improved it, thanks a **lot**.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `password = password.join(alc[0])` or `password += alc[0]`

`A.join(b)` does not change `A`. It makes a new string which is same as `A+b` and returns it, but `A` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler version of what you want to do:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import string

vals = {'a': string.ascii_lowercase,
        'b': string.ascii_uppercase,
        '$': '0123456789',
        '#': '!#%&?@()[]<>*+,.~:;=-_\\/',
       }

pattern = sys.argv[1]

password = ''.join(random.choice(vals[c]) for c in pattern) # assumes that there are no invalid characters in the input

password = ''.join(random.choice(vals[c][0]) for c in pattern if c in vals) # takes only the valid characters in the input
```

`random.shuffle` is a relatively expensive operation, shuffling the an entire list. On the other hand, `random.choice` picks a random element in an iterable.

Hope this helps